# Changing DEM with 10 meter cell size into 30 meter cell size in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.5

I have a 10 meter cell size Oregon DEM that I would like to match my Northern California DEM thats at a 30 meter cell size.

How would I go about changing the Oregon DEM cell size from a 10 meters to 30 meters using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by extent you mean the raster cell size.  According to [ESRI Altering The Resolution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/altering-the-resolution.htm) you have two options.

1) [Interpolation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm)

2) [Aggregation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/aggregate.htm)

I also believe it is possible to simply export the current 10x10 raster to a 30x30 raster by simply changing the cell in the export popup window (see image below).  But I am not sure how this aggregates the data.
[image]

Comment: I see. If i was going to try this exporting method to change the cell size, would i just be multipliying the cx and cy by 3?

Comment: Yes. Just change the cell size in the export dialog to the desired size (in your case 30 , 30) and export.  Again, I am not sure how the aggregation works when this is done in this manner.